# Adding redirects in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I am looking for some advice to help with the following scenario (I am still learning VB.net with ASP) I have looked on Google but I have hit a dead end now.

the first issue that I am having is trying to redirect www.samplesite.com/press.aspx to www.samplesite.com/press/press.aspx I have tried to use Rewrite Rules in the web.config without success.

the next issue I am having is I want any request for the homepage not using the default url to redirect to the default url, it also needs to preserve the query string if any.  for example please see below:

https://samplesite.com/home.aspx?key=value

Returns a 301 redirect to:

https://samplesite.com/?key=value

And:

https://samplesite.com/home.aspx/*anything*?key=value

Redirects to:

https://samplesite.com/?key=value

I would be grateful for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for asp.net routing and want to define custom url patterns or generate urls based on route parameters. These should give you some hints:

[ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx)

[URL Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing)

Comment: Thanks Mubarek,  I did have a look at those links but I don't think they will solve my issue,  these sample code dose not reflect what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://samplesite.com/some/route" />
```

Note: Place it in the head section.